# How can I mapped through this object from firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Getting the users collection from firestore:

```
  useEffect(() => {
        if (currentUser) {
          const unsubscribe = db
            .collection("users")
            .doc(uid)
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          const arr = [];
          arr.push({
            ...snapshot.data(),
          });

          setUsers(arr);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
        });

      return () => {
        unsubscribe();
      };
    }
  }, [currentUser]);
```

This is what is shows where I `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));`

```
[
  {
    1: { others: "books", items: { Item1: true, Item2: true } },
    2: {
      items: { Item3: true, Item2: true },
      others: "books",
    },

    displayName: Inigi,
    address: "US",
  },
];
```

I am new to react so this is quite confusing to me. How do I retrieve and display those `1` and `2`?

I tried this but it does not work and I keep on getting an error:"

> TypeError: _user$.items.map is not a function

```
 {user["1"]?.items.map((index) => (
                  <li>{index.Item1}</li>
                ))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{user["1"]?.others}`

Comment: thank you. Displaying the other does work, but how can I display all of those under `items`

Comment: You can use other loop like that: `{user["1"]?.items.map(...)}`

Comment: I'm really sorry. I keep on getting this error `TypeError: _user$.items.map is not a function` with these codes `{user["1"]?.items.map((index) => (<li{index.Item1}</li> ))}`

Comment: Can you ask another question with code and description detail?

Comment: You can try `{user["1"]?.items?.map?.(...)`

Comment: There's no error but it does not display the data `{user["1"]?.items?.map?.((index) => (
                  <li>{index.Item1}</li>
                ))}`